# No me devuelve ningún valor

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Buenas tengo este código que me devuelve valores de acuerdo a las variables. En las lineas que debe devolver valores en ciertas celdas especificas no me devuelve nada. Agradezco si me pueden ayudar.

```
function llenaAlumnos(valorJ2, valorL2, valorC4) {

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var baseSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Base");

  var planillaSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Planilla");
  
  var baseData = baseSheet.getRange("A2:P" + baseSheet.getLastRow()).getValues();

  
  var planillaData = [];

  
  for (var i = 0; i < baseData.length; i++) {

    if (baseData[i][2] == valorJ2 && baseData[i][3] == valorL2 && baseData[i][4] == valorC4) 
{

      planillaData.push(baseData[i].slice(5, 15)); // Columnas G a L

      


//aca no me devuelve los valores

      // Escribir valores en celdas específicas en la hoja "Planilla"
      planillaSheet.getRange("D3").setValue(baseData[i][15]); // Columna P, celda D3
      planillaSheet.getRange("F4").setValue(baseData[i][18]);  // Columna S, celda F4
      planillaSheet.getRange("D5").setValue(baseData[i][19]);  // Columna T, celda D5
      planillaSheet.getRange("J4").setValue(baseData[i][0]);   // Columna A, celda J4
      planillaSheet.getRange("L4").setValue(baseData[i][1]);   // Columna B, celda L4
    }
  }
  
  return planillaData;
}
```

En esta opción me da error Error Excepción: No tienes permiso para llamar a setValue (línea 15)

```
function llenaAlumnos(valorJ2, valorL2, valorC4) {


  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var baseSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Base");

  var planillaSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Planilla");

  
  var baseData = baseSheet.getRange("A2:P" + baseSheet.getLastRow()).getValues();

  
  var planillaData = [];

  
  for (var i = 0; i < baseData.length; i++) {

    if (baseData[i][2] == valorJ2 && baseData[i][3] == valorL2 && baseData[i][4] == valorC4)
 {

      planillaData.push(baseData[i].slice(5, 15)); // Columnas G a L

      
      // Escribir valores en celdas específicas en la hoja "Planilla"

      planillaSheet.getRange("D3").setValue(baseData[i][15]); // Columna P, celda D3

      planillaSheet.getRange("F4").setValue(baseData[i][18]);  // Columna S, celda F4

      planillaSheet.getRange("D5").setValue(baseData[i][19]);  // Columna T, celda D5

      planillaSheet.getRange("J4").setValue(baseData[i][0]);   // Columna A, celda J4

      planillaSheet.getRange("L4").setValue(baseData[i][1]);   // Columna B, celda L4


    }

  }
  
  return planillaData;
}
```

Comment: Hola, tu idea es usuarla como una fórmula dentro de una celda? De ser así, no es posible modificar los valores de otras celdas con una fórmula personalizada

Comment: mi idea es usarla con un boton, que llama a llenaAlumnos